# Angular reload resource that is being watched

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I think this seems like an obvious question, but my brain seems to be a bit fried.

I have a resource

```
Book = $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"});
book = Book.get(1);
```

I want to refresh the object to get changes from the server.
I know I can do that by repeating `book = Book.get(book.id)`, but that would mean that everything on the page that's watching `book` would temporarily get nulled until the query returned and functions that operate on it might crash.

I want to add a reload method to instances that updates any changed fields once the query returns from the server. My best attempt so far is:

```
$reload = function() {
    var model = this;

    Book.get(model.id, function(data) { // success
      angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
          model[key] = value;
      }
    }
}
```

Two questions
a) Is this the "angular" way to do it, or is there a more elegant way?
a) How do I add this $refresh method when defining the resource so that it gets included on every instance created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to extent it's prototype:

```
var Book = $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"});
Book.prototype.reload = function(callback) {
    return this.get(this.id, callback);
}

var book = Book.get(1);
book.reload(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

thanks to: @mathew-berg (Mathew Berg) for making fixes on my code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. How is your model structured?  From the $resource docs:  "Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data."
2. Roll your own API interaction in an Angular Service so that you can control the async behavior:

   ```
   yourApp.factory('BookService', function($q) {

      //Other API calls here

      function reload() {
         var deferred = $q.defer();

         $http.get('/someUrl').
         success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //Massage your data here... then
            deferred.resolve(data);
         }).
         error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject('There was a problem updating the books');
         });

         return deferred.promise;
      }

      return {
         reload: reload
      }
   });

   //In your conttroller or directive that holds your model
   books = BookService.reload();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@num8er's solution wouldn't even run without crashing for me.  Maybe we're using different versions of angular?  (I'm on 1.4.x at the moment.)  In particular, I had to change `get()` to `$get()`, but I was also looking to reload the object without having pass in a custom callback to capture it from everywhere I called reload, so I added that to the inner part.

I had to do:

```
var Book = $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"});
Book.prototype.reload = function() {
    var book = this;
    book.$get(book.id, function (new_book) {
        book = new_book;  // replace old book object with newly reloaded one
    });
};

var book = Book.get(1);
book.reload();
```